# Entering UK on a Tourist Visa after refusal of citizenship application

Tags: visas, uk

I would like to enter the United Kingdom on a tourist visa for a short visit.

Unfortunately my citizenship application was refused earlier *but* is under appeal at the moment. I am a citizen of Argentina.

Comment: I see the close vote, but it IS a tourist travel question - let's give it a chance guys.
To @user14013 - what citizenship are yo, and what was the reason for refusal?

Comment: @Mark Mayo: Sorry, I can't completely describe the categories of British nationals in a 600 character comment. You can find a comprehensive explanation of the term in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_citizen

Comment: One of the reasons for refusing a tourist visa **to the USA** is that the officers believe you want to move to the USA eventually, making you a "stay risk." An engaged woman I know was told to hide her ring when visiting her fiancé for this reason. If the UK has something similar, you may have a problem.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo after all that, a citizen of Argentina :/

Comment: @user14013: Why did you claim to be a British Overseas citizen?

Comment: "an overseas citizen" could just mean "a citizen of some country that is not the UK" @Tor-EinarJarnbjo

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Whilst "an overseas citizen" would usually in this context suggest that they are a British Overseas Citizen, I think it's just a question of bad English on their part: OP thought s/he could say "overseas citizen" to mean "a citizen of an overseas country".

Comment: Do you have a visa or do you plan to apply for one? On what basis did you apply for citizenship? Are you a resident of Argentina? I don't particularly know UK law but I think all this could have an impact.

Answer (score 3):

Argentine citizens don't need a visa to visit UK. From [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/argentina/tourism):

> However, you should bring the [same documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you’d need to apply for a
>   visa, to show to officers at the UK border.
>
> You may want to apply for a visa if you have a criminal record or
>   you’ve previously been refused entry into the UK.

Comment: I am not a British overseas citizen, I am Argentinian.

Comment: @user14013 this was not clear from your question. However the same rules apply also for Argentine citizens.

Comment: That's true but I don't think it fully addresses the question, which is whether the failed citizenship application has an impact on touristic visits to the country, confusion on visa aside.